# GraalVM, Apache Kafka: Could not find a public no-argument constructor for org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, graalvm-native-image

I am currently working on a Java-Application which is a Kafka-Producer. I have already finished and fully tested the code with Maven, everything worked fine. Then I waned to get a Graal-Native-Image for executing the producer Code.

I am building the project with "mvn -Pnative package" and everything is getting built fine. (also using the maven profile from the docs: (https://graalvm.github.io/native-build-tools/latest/maven-plugin.html)). When trying to start the image via "./MyApp" I am getting the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:465)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:290)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:317)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:302)
        at Main.main(Main.java:23)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Could not find a public no-argument constructor for org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:397)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:401)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:440)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:425)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:380)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.<init>()
        at java.base@17.0.8/java.lang.Class.checkMethod(DynamicHub.java:1038)
        at java.base@17.0.8/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(DynamicHub.java:1204)
        at java.base@17.0.8/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(DynamicHub.java:2754)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:395)
        ... 8 more
```

The following code snippet represents the code where the error seems to happen:

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        properties.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081");
        properties.put("key.serializer", Class.forName("org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"));
        properties.put("value.serializer", Class.forName("io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer"));

        final org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer<String, GenericRecord> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("Stopping Producer");
            producer.close();
        }));
```

My guess was that the Kafka Depedency just isnt being imported properly, but trying it without it in my pom.xml the "mvn package" command wouldnt even work without errors. By the way I am using the latest Kafka Version.
I also tried using as less Dependencies as possible and looked if one of the would be the problem. Is there any specific GraalVM configs I am missing? I am new to the topic.

I hope that is all information relevant for that kind of problem otherwise I would of course share it, if something was missing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Don't use `Class.forName` when you can just use `StringSerializer.class` 2) Seems like your native image doesn't include external dependencies, or you're not running the code with a complete classpath... Successful building and packaging doesn't address runtime errors

Comment: It was indeed a problem with the dependencies, in fact I solved the problem with some entries in my "reflect-config.json" file. Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to add your complete solution below as an answer

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem I had was that I didnt know about configuring the GraalVM with Kafka at all. In the following link I found the solution to my problem in adding the requested json file for the confluent schema registry to my project: https://jeqo.github.io/posts/2022-03-18-kafka-clients-graalvm/

Comment: I think your answer could be improved if you post your corrected code that resolves the problem.