How to fix the runtime issue in YouTube Data API v3 OAuth classes instantiation (runtime) issue when compiled to native using GraalVM?
How to fix below runtime issue with YouTube Data API v3 failing to instantiate the Google OAuth class (oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets) when compiled to the native binaries using the GraalVM? Here's the story behind:
I have a Spring Boot Shell application that connects to the YouTube Data API v3.
It uses OAuth, so that it can download my playlists in future.
At present the authentication works fine when it runs on the JVM. However, once compiled to Native binaries using GraalVM, I get "unable to create new instance of class com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets" in runtime.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to create new instance of class com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets because it has no accessible default constructor
        at com.google.api.client.util.Types.handleExceptionForNewInstance(Types.java:162)
        at com.google.api.client.util.Types.newInstance(Types.java:117)
        at com.google.api.client.util.Data.newMapInstance(Data.java:550)
        at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:766)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets
        at java.base@22.0.1/java.lang.Class.newInstance(DynamicHub.java:749)
        at com.google.api.client.util.Types.newInstance(Types.java:113)
        ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets.<init>()
        at java.base@22.0.1/java.lang.Class.checkExecutable(DynamicHub.java:1101)
        at java.base@22.0.1/java.lang.Class.checkConstructor(DynamicHub.java:1082)
        at java.base@22.0.1/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(DynamicHub.java:1272)
        at java.base@22.0.1/java.lang.Class.newInstance(DynamicHub.java:736)
        ... 40 more

The documentation says that OAuth libraries support the Native compilation, which I suppose then should be having the hints and meta-data.
This is my POM:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>GraamVM5</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>GraamVM5</name>
    <description>GraamVM5</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <spring-shell.version>3.3.0-RC1</spring-shell.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.shell</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-shell-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.32.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-youtube</artifactId>
            <version>v3-rev20240514-2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.31.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>1.36.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.shell</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-shell-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.shell</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-shell-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-shell.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
                <version>26.39.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>



And the Spring Shell application (auth1 is the parameter to start the authentication).
package com.demo.command;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTubeScopes;
import org.springframework.shell.standard.ShellComponent;
import org.springframework.shell.standard.ShellMethod;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

@ShellComponent
public class CommandAuth1 {

    public static final String clientCredentialJson =
            "./authsecrets/client_secret.json";

    private static final JsonFactory jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();
    private static Collection<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>(YouTubeScopes.all());
    private static DataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory;

    static {
        try {
            dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(new File( "./authsessions"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public CommandAuth1() throws IOException {
    }

    @ShellMethod
    void auth1() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Auth1.. ");
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        YouTube youTubeService = new YouTube.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, authorize())
                .setApplicationName("YouTubeClientTest7")
                .build();
        System.out.println("Auth1.. done.");
    }

    /** Authorizes the installed application to access user's protected data. */
    private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
        // load client secrets
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(jsonFactory,
                new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(clientCredentialJson))));
        // set up authorization code flow
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientSecrets,scopes).setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
                .build();
        // authorize
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    }

}

Any idea how I can rid of the InstantiationException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets issue and get the authentication to complete?
Build steps are pretty straight forward:
mvn -Pnative clean package
mvn -Pnative native:compile

Let me know if you have any questions.

I think the link given in the response for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76912248/graalvm-apache-kafka-could-not-find-a-public-no-argument-constructor-for-org-a can help you.
